# Using geometric mean to take median of an even number of data points

Tags: median, geometric-mean

When taking the median of a data set consisting of an even number of data points, generally the arithmetic mean of the two middle points is taken.

Suppose a set of data points has a suspected logarithmic distribution. For example, with the prices of houses, it would make sense that the distribution is logarithmic, e.g. $\$10000$, $\$100000$, $\$1000000$, etc. Would it be more appropriate to use the geometric mean when taking the median of a set of house prices with an even number of data points? How should this be communicated?

Comment: In what sense do you intend "more appropriate"?  It seems to me that if the difference between these two methods of computing a median has any material impact on the results, that would be *prima facie* evidence that your results are strongly dependent on the lognormal assumption, suggesting you have more fundamental issues to deal with than the niceties of how medians are reported.